# What are the correct configuration settings for a Web API using MSAL.NET and on-prem ADFS 2019

Tags: c#, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal, adfs

Has anyone successfully developed a Web API in .NET6 that uses the Microsoft Authentication Library for .NET (MSAL.NET) and an on-prem ADFS 2019 server to authorise access to a REST API? What AD FS configuration settings did you specify in your Web API appSettings.json file?

I’m trying to implement the Client Credential Grant Flow as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/ad-fs-openid-connect-oauth-flows-scenarios?source=recommendations#client-credentials-grant-flow) article. I have ADFS 2019 running in a test environment and I have used the AD FS management console to setup an Application group containing a server application and a Web API. The server application has been configured with a Client Id and a shared secret.

The server application is able to query AD FS 2019 using the [IConfidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.iconfidentialclientapplication.acquiretokenforclient?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.Identity.Client.IConfidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=azure-dotnet) method to get an access token with no issues. The issue is when the server application calls the REST API and presents the token in the HTTP GET request. The REST API returns 500 Internal Server Error with the following exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://{My ADFS Server FQDN}/adfs/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

The Web API appears to be querying an invalid AD FS endpoint. The AD FS Management Console shows that the AD FS service is listening on the following OpenID Connect endpoint:

/adfs/.well-known/openid-configuration,

however the Web API is trying to query:

/adfs/**v2.0**/.well-known/openid-configuration

My Web API Startup.ConfigureServices method looks like the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration);

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            services.AddSwaggerGen();
        }
```

My appSettings.json file looks like the following:

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://{My ADFS Server FQDN}/adfs/",
    "ClientId": {Server app Client Id goes here}
    "Tenant": "adfs",
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Debug"
    }
 },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Is there something that I need to add or change in the appSettings file so that MSAL.NET will successfully communicate with AD FS 2019?

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late on this but this is how I did it.
I used this package [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect)

Configure Method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/";
        })
        .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.MetadataAddress = Configuration["ADFSInfo:metadatAaddress"];
            options.ClientId = Configuration["ADFSInfo:clientId"];
            options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
            options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
            options.UsePkce = true;

            options.Scope.Clear();
            options.Scope.Add("openid");

            options.SaveTokens = true;
        });
    }
```

Here's the appsetting.json:

```
{
"ADFSInfo": {
"metadataAddress": "ADFSServer/adfs/.well-known/openid-configuration",
"clientId": "****-****-****-****-************"
},
```

Make sure you use the right Application Group in ADFS, Here's another example which shows both the ADFS and Asp.Net core configuration [Example](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/authenticating-to-active-directory-federation-services-adfs-2019-with-net-core-3-1-b0bf012fc183)